Cannot Update User Profile in Flutter
I am a beginner in flutter development, i want to call the API to update the user profile, in the API one of them consist of 'image' & 'proof' field,that field can be left blank, but the problem is whenever i left those fields empty and click the 'edit' button, I always receive this response from the server :

{
  "status": 500,
  "message": "The \"path\" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array"
}

my purpose is i want to empty 'image' & 'proof' fields if i not choose any image & background image, but if i choose it i want those field is fullfill with the image path
i hope there is someone that can help me to find the solution of this problem,
here is my code :
// Auth Service
class AuthService {
  static String? token;
  static String? bioDateId;

  final TokenManager tokenManager = TokenManager();
  final BiodateIdManager biodateIdManager = BiodateIdManager();
// Update Bio
  Future<bool> updateBio({
    required String firstName,
    required String lastName,
    required String birthDate,
    required String gender,
    required String phone,
    required String address,
    required String province,
    required String regencies,
    required String institutionName,
    required String pupils,
    required String field,
    String? image,
    String? proof,
  }) async {
    String? token = await tokenManager.getToken();
    String? bioDateId = await biodateIdManager.getBiodateId();
    try {
      // Create a Map for form data
      Map<String, dynamic> formDataMap = {
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName,
        "birthDate": birthDate,
        "gender": gender,
        "phone": phone,
        "address": address,
        "province": province,
        "regencies": regencies,
        "institutionName": institutionName,
        "field": field,
        "pupils": pupils,
      };

      // Get MIME type for the files and add to formDataMap if not null
      if (proof != null && proof.isNotEmpty) {
        String? proofMimeType = lookupMimeType(proof);
        if (proofMimeType != null) {
          MultipartFile proofMultipartFile = await MultipartFile.fromFile(
            proof,
            filename: 'proof.png',
            contentType: MediaType.parse(proofMimeType),
          );
          formDataMap["proof"] = proofMultipartFile;
        } else {
          debugPrint('Invalid proof MIME type');
        }
      }

      if (image != null && image.isNotEmpty) {
        String? imageMimeType = lookupMimeType(image);
        if (imageMimeType != null) {
          MultipartFile imageMultipartFile = await MultipartFile.fromFile(
            image,
            filename: 'image.png',
            contentType: MediaType.parse(imageMimeType),
          );
          formDataMap["image"] = imageMultipartFile;
        } else {
          debugPrint('Invalid image MIME type');
        }
      }

      var response = await Dio().put(
        "http://192.168.1.5:3000/user/update-biodate?id=$bioDateId",
        data: FormData.fromMap(formDataMap),
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
          },
        ),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Update successful
        return true;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to Update Bio : ${response.data['message']}');
      }
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      if (e.response?.statusCode == 400) {
        debugPrint('Error 400: ${e.response?.data}');
        throw Exception('Update Bio failed: ${e.response?.data['message']}');
      } else {
        debugPrint('Error: ${e.toString()}');
        throw Exception('Failed to Update Bio');
      }
    }
  }
}




// UpdateUserController
class UpdateUserController {
  final AuthService _authService = AuthService();
  UpdateUserModel updateUserModel = UpdateUserModel();

  TextEditingController firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lastNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController birthDateController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController genderController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController provinceController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController regenciesController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController institutionNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController studyFieldController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController uniqueIdController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController imageController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController proofController = TextEditingController();

  String? _selectedImagePath;
  String? _selectedProofPath;

  void setImagePath(String filePath) {
    _selectedImagePath = filePath;
    debugPrint('Selected image path set: $_selectedImagePath');
  }

  void setProofPath(String filePath) {
    _selectedProofPath = filePath;
    debugPrint('Selected proof path set: $_selectedProofPath');
  }

  void reset() {
    _selectedImagePath = null;
    _selectedProofPath = null;
    firstNameController.clear();
    lastNameController.clear();
    birthDateController.clear();
    genderController.clear();
    phoneController.clear();
    addressController.clear();
    provinceController.clear();
    regenciesController.clear();
    institutionNameController.clear();
    studyFieldController.clear();
    uniqueIdController.clear();
  }

  void dispose() {
    firstNameController.dispose();
    lastNameController.dispose();
    birthDateController.dispose();
    genderController.dispose();
    phoneController.dispose();
    addressController.dispose();
    provinceController.dispose();
    regenciesController.dispose();
    institutionNameController.dispose();
    studyFieldController.dispose();
    uniqueIdController.dispose();
  }

  bool fileExists(String path) {
    return File(path).existsSync();
  }

  Future<void> updateBio(BuildContext context) async {
    DialogHelper.showLoading(context);

    String firstName = firstNameController.text.trim();
    String lastName = lastNameController.text.trim();
    String birthDate = birthDateController.text.trim();
    String gender = genderController.text.trim();
    String phone = phoneController.text.trim();
    String address = addressController.text.trim();
    String province = provinceController.text.trim();
    String regencies = regenciesController.text.trim();
    String institutionName = institutionNameController.text.trim();
    String studyField = studyFieldController.text.trim();
    String uniqueId = uniqueIdController.text.trim();
    // String? image = imageController.text.trim();
    // String? proof = proofController.text.trim();
    String? image = _selectedImagePath;
    String? proof = _selectedProofPath;

    try {
      bool bioUpdated = await _authService.updateBio(
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        birthDate: birthDate,
        gender: gender,
        phone: phone,
        address: address,
        province: province,
        regencies: regencies,
        institutionName: institutionName,
        field: studyField,
        pupils: uniqueId,
        image: image,
        proof: proof,
      );
      DialogHelper.hideLoading(context);

      if (bioUpdated) {
        reset();
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const EduPassApp(
                      initialPageIndex: 4,
                    )));
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text('UpdateBio berhasil'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        ));
        debugPrint('UpdateBio berhasil');
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text('UpdateBio gagal'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        ));
        debugPrint('UpdateBio gagal');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      DialogHelper.hideLoading(context);
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Error: $e'),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      ));
      debugPrint('Error saat UpdateBio: $e');
    }
  }
}


// ProfileUserDetail
class ProfileDetailUser extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileDetailUser({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProfileDetailUser> createState() => _ProfileDetailUserState();
}

class _ProfileDetailUserState extends State<ProfileDetailUser> {
  String? _selectedImagePath;
  String? _selectedBackgroundPath;
  final UpdateUserController updateController = UpdateUserController();

  void _handleImageSelected(String filePath) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedImagePath = filePath;
      updateController.setImagePath(filePath);
      // updateController.imageController.text = filePath;
    });
    debugPrint('File path: $filePath');
  }

  void _handleBackgroundSelected(String filePath) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedBackgroundPath = filePath;
      updateController.setProofPath(filePath);
      // updateController.proofController.text = filePath;
    });
    debugPrint('File path: $filePath');
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ProfileUserController(),
      child: Consumer<ProfileUserController>(
        builder: (context, profileController, child) {
          if (profileController.isLoading) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          if (profileController.userData == null) {
            return ErrorScreen(onRetry: profileController.retryFetchUserData);
          }

          // Initialize UpdateUserController's text controllers with data from ProfileUserController
          updateController.firstNameController.text =
              profileController.userData!['biodate']['firstName'] ?? '';
          updateController.lastNameController.text =
              profileController.userData!['biodate']['lastName'] ?? '';
          String birthDate =
              profileController.userData!['biodate']['birthDate'] ?? '';
          if (birthDate.isNotEmpty) {
            updateController.birthDateController.text =
                birthDate.substring(0, 10); // Format date
          }

          updateController.genderController.text =
              profileController.userData!['biodate']['gender'] ?? '';
          updateController.phoneController.text =
              profileController.userData!['biodate']['phone'] ?? '';
          updateController.addressController.text =
              profileController.userData!['biodate']['address'] ?? '';
          updateController.provinceController.text =
              profileController.userData!['biodate']['province'] ?? '';
          updateController.regenciesController.text =
              profileController.userData!['biodate']['regencies'] ?? '';
          updateController.institutionNameController.text =
              profileController.userData!['biodate']['institutionName'] ?? '';
          updateController.studyFieldController.text =
              profileController.userData!['biodate']['field'] ?? '';
          updateController.uniqueIdController.text =
              profileController.userData!['biodate']['pupils'] ?? '';
          // updateController.imageController.text =
          //     profileController.userData!['biodate']['image'];
          // updateController.proofController.text =
          //     profileController.userData!['biodate']['proof'];
          // updateController.setImagePath(
          //     profileController.userData!['biodate']['image'] ?? '');
          // updateController.setProofPath(
          //     profileController.userData!['biodate']['proof'] ?? '');

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              elevation: 0,
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          const EduPassApp(initialPageIndex: 4),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              title: Text(
                'Profile',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            body: Container(
              color: Colors.grey.shade100,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 16, right: 16, top: 16, bottom: 30),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    UserAvatarField(onFileSelected: _handleImageSelected),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    if (_selectedImagePath != null) ...[
                      Text('Selected file: $_selectedImagePath'),
                      // Jika Anda ingin menampilkan gambar yang diunggah
                      Image.file(
                        File(_selectedImagePath!),
                        height: 200,
                      ),
                    ],
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ProfileTextField(
                      label: 'Nama Depan',
                      placeholder: 'John',
                      controller: updateController.firstNameController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ProfileTextField(
                      label: 'Nama Belakang',
                      placeholder: 'Doe',
                      controller: updateController.lastNameController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ProfileTextField(
                      label: 'Email',
                      placeholder: 'stevejobs@gmail.com',
                      enabled: false,
                      controller: TextEditingController(
                        text: profileController.userData!['email'] ?? '',
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ProfileDateField(
                      label: 'Select Date',
                      placeholder: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                      controller: updateController.birthDateController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        debugPrint(
                            'Selected Date: ${updateController.birthDateController.text}');
                      },
                      child: const Text('Print Selected Date'),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    DropdownField(
                      label: 'Jenis Kelamin',
                      items: const ['Pria', 'Wanita', ''],
                      controller: updateController.genderController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        debugPrint(
                            'Selected Gender: ${updateController.genderController.text}');
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    UploadImageField(onFileSelected: _handleBackgroundSelected),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    if (_selectedBackgroundPath != null) ...[
                      Text('Selected file: $_selectedBackgroundPath'),
                      // Jika Anda ingin menampilkan gambar yang diunggah
                      Image.file(
                        File(_selectedBackgroundPath!),
                        height: 200,
                      ),
                    ],
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ProfileTextField(
                      label: 'Provinsi',
                      placeholder: 'California',
                      controller: updateController.provinceController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ProfileTextField(
                      label: 'Regencies',
                      placeholder: 'San Francisco',
                      controller: updateController.regenciesController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ProfileTextField(
                      label: 'Nomor HP',
                      placeholder: '08123456789',
                      controller: updateController.phoneController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ProfileTextField(
                      label: 'Alamat',
                      placeholder: 'Jalan Jendral Sudirman No 1',
                      controller: updateController.addressController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ProfileTextField(
                      label: 'Nama Instansi',
                      placeholder: 'Harvard University',
                      controller: updateController.institutionNameController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ProfileTextField(
                      label: 'Bidang Studi/Jurusan',
                      placeholder: 'Teknik Informatika',
                      controller: updateController.studyFieldController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16),
                    ProfileTextField(
                      label: 'NIM/NISN',
                      placeholder: '123123123',
                      controller: updateController.uniqueIdController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 32),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        updateController.updateBio(context);
                        updateController.reset();

                        // String? image = _selectedImagePath;
                        // String? proof = _selectedBackgroundPath;
                        // updateController.updateBio(context, image, proof);
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 40, vertical: 16),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        'Edit',
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}




Your code combines app state management with presentation in the ProfileDetailUser widget. That is not a good strategy to build a maintainable app.
My suggestion is to review the list of state management approaches for Flutter and select one that suit you. I have work successfully with the BloC pattern (together with GetIt for dependency injection).
When done properly, separating app state and presentation will prevent problems like yours.
